# Overridden comparator and Collections.sort

Tags: java, collections, compare

```
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<A>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(A a, A b) {
            return -a.getId().compareTo(b.getId());
        }
    });
```

If you put a minus in front of the return value in the comparator, will it correspond to reverseOrder method?

```
        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<A>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(A a, A b) {
            return a.getId().compareTo(b.getId());
        }
    }));
```

I mean, will it always work right?

Comment: It works unless the result of `compareTo` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: I prefer to use `b.getId().compareTo(a.getId())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Integer.MIN_VALUE` is also `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

If you can guarantee that `compareTo` can't return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it will work the same (assuming the `compareTo` method is implemented correctly).

Otherwise, it would be safer to use the `reverseOrder` method, or to swap `a` and `b` in the expression (which is what `reverseOrder` does).

Comment: or to use [`Comparator.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed())